# Objective-C How do I compress the video ONLY and not the video AND text overlay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, video, snapchat

I am basically using AVAssetExportSession and AVMutableVideoComposition to add my text overlay on top of the video and then compress the video. At the moment, when I compressed the video to AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality, it also ruined the quality of the text overlay... I dont want this to happen. I just want to lower the quality on the video ONLY and keep the text overlay on top of the video sharp and not pixelated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Compress the video, then add the text overlay.

Comment: how do i do that though, is my question.

Comment: @Adp the same way you are doing it now, just move the compression code before the code to add text.

Comment: but..i am using AVAssetExportSession for compression AND exporting...so I dont understand how to do it with that. How do I compress the video AND THEN add the text on top and THEN save the video?